# yii2 conditional validation is not working serverside?

Tags: validation, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rule

I am using username field in form,i set rule like below.

```
['username', 'required','when' => function($model) {
            return $model->pin == true;
        }],
```

(i.e)when the property pin goes true that time only i need username field required,all are working fine in clientside,but this validation falis on serverside,what is wrong on my code.

UPDATE:

controller code

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $model = new Test();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->customValidation()) {
        if($model->validate())
        {
            //
        }
    } 
    return $this->render('testView', [
    'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

model

```
public $username;
public $pin = false;
public function rules()
{
 return [
    ['username', 'required','message' => 'You must enter username','when'      => function($model) {
        return $model->pin == true;
    }],
];
}
public function customValidation()
{
if()
{
    $this->pin = true;
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

view

```
if($model->pin)
{
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(); ?>
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it fails on the server side? And not on a client side? The way it is written indicates it should not work on the client side.

Comment: yes sure when i open firebug and change field id that time its not working

Comment: Does your `customValidation()` method work? Empty `if ()` ends with error...

Comment: no it's not empty some validation is there,sorry for inconvience

Comment: So... Maybe it does not work because `customValidation()` returns `false`? In that case `$model->validate()` is not called at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `whenClient` for this to work on the client side:

```
[
    'username', 'required', 
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->pin == true;
    },
    'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
        // JS condition here
    }"
],
```

where JS condition depends on the DOM structure you have got. For example if pin property is checkboxed with id `pin` this can be:

```
'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
    return $('#pin').is(':checked');
}"
```

UPDATE:
If you just set `pin` property in model you can modify the validation rule like that:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        // other validation rules
    ];
    if ($this->pin) {
        $rules[] = ['username', 'required'];
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,but problem is the property pin not in form field,it is used only inside model

Comment: Is it changed dynamically or once set in model it's passed to the view?

Comment: i am initialize first time like public $pin = false;

Comment: after call some function it goes true

Comment: See my update. It would be much easier if you stop revealing pieces of information required for the proper answer one by one.

Comment: You are changing the `pin` only on server side, right? So when validation rules are checked `pin` state is already set. And it doesn't work? Please provide you model, controller's action and view in this case.